# Elastic Beanstalk - '.ebextensions/02_setup.config' - Contains invalid key: '03_wsgipass'

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Using this guide to try to deploy my django app which uses channels: https://medium.com/@elspanishgeek/how-to-deploy-django-channels-2-x-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk-8621771d4ff0

This is my `02_setup.config`

```
container_commands:
  00_pip_upgrade:
    command: "source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && pip install --upgrade pip"
    ignoreErrors: false
  01_migrate:
    command: "django-admin.py migrate"
    leader_only: true
  02_collectstatic:
    command: "django-admin.py collectstatic --noinput"
03_wsgipass:
    command: 'echo "WSGIPassAuthorization On" >> ../wsgi.conf'
```

When running `eb create django-env` I get:

```
Printing Status:
2020-06-17 16:11:36    INFO    createEnvironment is starting.
2020-06-17 16:11:38    INFO    Using elasticbeanstalk-us-west-2-041741961231 as Amazon S3 storage bucket for environment data.
2020-06-17 16:11:39    WARN    Error processing file (Skipping): '.ebextensions/02_setup.config' - Contains invalid key: '03_wsgipass'. For information about valid keys, see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html
2020-06-17 16:12:00    INFO    Created security group named: sg-09fcbd00450e2438d
2020-06-17 16:12:15    INFO    Created load balancer named: awseb-e-3-AWSEBLoa-1E8WRE8X90Q7D
2020-06-17 16:12:15    INFO    Created security group named: awseb-e-3um2qhsms9-stack-AWSEBSecurityGroup-1OH8TOJHUVWOT
2020-06-17 16:12:15    INFO    Created Auto Scaling launch configuration named: awseb-e-3um2qhsms9-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingLaunchConfiguration-7V5MPL4ZNZOG
2020-06-17 16:13:35    INFO    Created Auto Scaling group named: awseb-e-3um2qhsms9-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup-6WNX8OQK3WQO
2020-06-17 16:13:35    INFO    Waiting for EC2 instances to launch. This may take a few minutes.
2020-06-17 16:13:50    INFO    Created Auto Scaling group policy named: arn:aws:autoscaling:us-west-2:041741961231:scalingPolicy:b25f0129-aec8-414c-9b64-72b95986648c:autoScalingGroupName/awseb-e-3um2qhsms9-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup-6WNX8OQK3WQO:policyName/awseb-e-3um2qhsms9-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingScaleUpPolicy-N1XL34JAPA6S
2020-06-17 16:13:50    INFO    Created Auto Scaling group policy named: arn:aws:autoscaling:us-west-2:041741961231:scalingPolicy:f6eecd79-39ee-475d-b927-ed1a5dc205d5:autoScalingGroupName/awseb-e-3um2qhsms9-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingGroup-6WNX8OQK3WQO:policyName/awseb-e-3um2qhsms9-stack-AWSEBAutoScalingScaleDownPolicy-155DVPR0DTOK
2020-06-17 16:13:50    INFO    Created CloudWatch alarm named: awseb-e-3um2qhsms9-stack-AWSEBCloudwatchAlarmHigh-CPMPHOMFE9IT
2020-06-17 16:13:50    INFO    Created CloudWatch alarm named: awseb-e-3um2qhsms9-stack-AWSEBCloudwatchAlarmLow-UVP8LL57BLI4
2020-06-17 16:17:49    INFO    Successfully launched environment: django-env
```

What's wrong with the `03_wsgipass` command?

Answer (score 0):

The **indentation** of `03_wsgipass` is incorrect. Thus EB wants to use it as a new section in your config file, rather then a part of `container_commands`.